# Redirect::to() not redirecting application to specific controller resource

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I am new to laravel.Here i am creating a basic form validation page in laravel.I am using RESTful controller to perform CRUD action.Here i created a

```
taskController controller.
```

In my view/taskController directory i have the following pages

> 1.create.blade.php
>
> 2.store.blade.php
>
> 3.index.blade.php

I have a form in my `taskController/create` resource.My plan is whenever i submit the form ,if validation is successful it will redirect me `taskController/store` page.Otherwise it will send me back to `taskController/create` page with the validation errors.But On success or On failure i can not redirect my application to any of my page.***No error is thrown also***.Why is this happening and how i can solve this?

Here is the store() method of my taskController page:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
 {
        //
        $rules = array(

             'email'    => 'required|email',     // required and must be unique in the ducks table
             'comment'  => 'required',
             'agree'    => 'required|accepted'           // required and has to match the password field
      );
       $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
       if ($validator->fails()) {

        // get the error messages from the validator
           $messages = $validator->messages();


        return Redirect::to('taskController/create');// not working


       }else{
        return Redirect::to('taskController/store'); // not working

       }
    }
```

Comment: which version are you on?

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
return redirect('taskController/create');
```

Comment: try 'return view('taskController/create');'

Comment: i tried with View::make() before ..it worked..actually i want to know why Redirect::to () not working..it is just for learning purpose..:)

Answer (score 0):

I think route action to `store` method will never as long as it is a resource controller. If the controller is not resource and the request is `Get` then yeah you can redirect.

If you are on Laravel `5.2` you can redirect to a controller method something like

```
return redirect()->action('taskController/store')
```

[Laravel Redirect Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#redirecting-controller-actions)

Comment: can you clarify one thing that is will it go to a file under the directory called  resource/views/taskController/store or it will just invoke the store() method inside taskController.php page?

Comment: so where is your controller located?

Comment: it is under app/http/controllers directory

Comment: It won't go here `resource/views/taskController/store` but rather here `app/Http/Controller/taskController@store` method

Comment: that makes sence ...so there is no way to redirect to store.blade with redirect class instead of View::make() ?

Comment: [I think you are not  familiar with MVC. Try read MVC first](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/model-view-controller-MVC)

Answer (score 0):

Did you used     `Use Redirect;` on the top importing the redirect functionality hope this should help

Comment: yes i used the namespace specification at the beginning

Comment: you arent redirected and not getting any error?  return redirect()->action('taskController@store') tried?

Comment: i dont want to visit the store method inside my taskController controller,rather i want to visit a page called store.blade.php inside taskController subfolder under " resource/views/taskController/store.blade"

Comment: return view('taskController.store');